# Removing some valu etypes for Multidimensional Array Angular TypeScript

Tags: angular

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
[{id:0, type:1, name:"a"}, {id:1, type:2, name:"b"}, {id:2, type:3, name:"c"}]
```

I want to splice/remove elements such that I get the output:

```
[{id:0, type:1}, {id:1, type:2}, {id:2, type:3}]
```

that is, I want to remove all elements of a particular type, not remove rows. Is there any solution for this?

Also, would be great if I can do the same thing with insert, that is Insert elements in each row for a new type.

Comment: This looks like a single-dimension array, where each element is an object. Have you tried using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array, and constructing a new object from each existing object?

Answer (score 0):

to remove a row with a certain "type", you can just use foreach :

```
let array = [{id:0, type:1, name:"a"}, {id:1, type:2, name:"b"}, {id:2, type:3, name:"c"}];
array = array.forEach((v) => v['yourtypetoremove'] = undefined);
```

Now if you want to add you can do the same but changing the undefined with the value you want.

Notice that when you set a field to undefined it will not exist but if you set it to null its value will be null.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with angular typescript code. is there any other solution? Maybe because the array i'm getting is a result of a service called..

Comment: what happens when you run the code from the array of the service. Could you please give more information of how you get the information from the service. Are you allowed to write to the service array ? If not where are you using the array ?

Comment: I got the solution for the same.. I created a new array and took only values that i needed from this array. That was by the easiest and the quickest way to do it..